# run subproccess in python3 on ubuntu (bash script)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

My results is only empty loop logs.

if i put manual in terminal this line command :

```
python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile --name SOCIAL_NETWORK_TEST --distpath packages/projectTest --workpath .cache/ app.py
```

then pack works fine.

Any suggestion.

```
        bashCommand = "python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile --name " + self.engineConfig.currentProjectName + " --distpath " + "projects/" + self.engineConfig.currentProjectName + "/Package/" + " --workpath .cache/ main.py"
        print("PACK DONE,")
        # no expirience
        import subprocess
        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        # self.myLogs = []
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b'\n'):
        #     self.testLog = str(line)
        #     self.LOGS.text = self.testLog
            print ("PACKAGE:",  str(line))
        print("Package application for linux ended.")
```

Comment: did you try stepping through your code in debugger?

Comment: There is no any message , no error just empty loop of logs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
output = subprocess.run(["your_scritp.sh", "param1", "param2"], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(output.stdout)
```

to see what you get back, should be a string of the output that you can iterate if multiline

Comment: can i use simple string (bashCommand )  "for your_scritp.sh" ? I see now "No such file or directory:"  must be shell ! Now i need to write shell file on disk based on my string ... I will try

Comment: in your case i suggest:
output = subprocess.run(["python3", "-m",  "PyInstaller", "--onefile", ....... till the end]...

Answer (score 1):

You can use iter to process lines as soon as the command outputs them: lines = iter(fd.readline, "")

```
from __future__ import print_function # Only Python 2.x
import subprocess

def execute(cmd):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line 
    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise  subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code,cmd)
bashCommand = "python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile --name " + self.engineConfig.currentProjectName + " --distpath " + "projects/" + self.engineConfig.currentProjectName + "/Package/" + " --workpath .cache/ main.py"
print("PACK DONE,")
execute(bashCommand)
```